# jQuery autoScroll to the nearest section

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the user is place in the top half of current section it automatically scroll top of that section.

Then if the user is in the bottom half of the current section it automatically scroll to the top next section.

```
function autoScroll(aid){
    var aTag = $("#"+ aid);
    body.animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},1500);
} 

$(window).scroll(function() {
      var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if(windowScroll < ($("#Section2").offset().top/2) && !(windowScroll > ($("#Section2").offset().top/2))){
                    section_id = 'Section1';
        }
        $(document).off('scroll');
        console.log(section_id);
        autoScroll(section_id);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x6xzh69v/2/

Comment: Its similar to this http://risenchurch.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a working example in [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/eJwJVv?editors=1010).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var origHeight = [];
  var curScroll = 0;
  var cumSumHeight = 0;
  var animHeight = 0;
  var i = 0;
  var timeoutVar;

$(".section").each(function(index) {
    origHeight.push($(this).height());
  });

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    curScroll = $("body").scrollTop();
    cumSumHeight = 0;

    while ((cumSumHeight + origHeight[i]) < curScroll) {
    cumSumHeight += origHeight[i];
      i++;
    }    

    if (i == 0) {
    if (curScroll < (origHeight[i] / 2)) {
         animHeight = 0;
      } else {
         animHeight = origHeight[i];
      }
    } else {
    if ((curScroll - cumSumHeight) < (origHeight[i] / 2)) {
         animHeight = cumSumHeight;
      } else {
         animHeight = origHeight[i] + cumSumHeight;
      }
    }
    clearTimeout(timeoutVar);
    timeoutVar = setTimeout(function() {
      $("body").stop(true,true).animate({
         scrollTop: animHeight
      }, 200);
    }, 300);
 });
});
```

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

#Section1 {
  background: red;
}

#Section2 {
  background: blue;
}

#Section3 {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="Section1" class="section"></section>
<section id="Section2" class="section"></section>
<section id="Section3" class="section"></section>
```